# How do you say "I'm calling in regards to (Alexis)" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, expresiones

How would you translate this sentence:

> Good afternoon, this is (Maria) calling from (business name) **in regards to** (Alexis).

Answer (score 4):

Also `con relación a`:

> [con relación a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VoYtQP9)
>
> 1. loc. prepos. En correspondencia con, o conforme a.
>   2. loc. prepos. con respecto a.

Translating as:

> Buenas tardes, soy María de *-business name-* y llamo/llamaba **con relación a** Alexis.

or `en relación con`

> [en relación con](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VoYtQP9)
>
> 1. loc. prepos. con relación a.

Translating as:

> Buenas tardes, soy María de *-business name-* y llamo/llamaba **en relación con** Alexis.

Answer (score 3):

The key here is "in regards to", which can be translated in Spanish as `a propósito de`

> [propósito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UOdvZX1)
>
> 3. m. Asunto, materia de que se trata.
>
> a propósito de
>
> 1. loc. prepos. acerca de.

So you could say

> Buenas tardes, soy María de *-business name-* y llamo/llamaba **a propósito de** Alexis

You could use equivalent forms like `Con respecto a`

> [con respecto a](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WC1YIHF), o con respecto de, o respecto a, o respecto de
>
> 1. locs. prepos. Acerca de, en lo que se refiere a.

Translating as:

> Buenas tardes, soy María de *-business name-* y llamo/llamaba **con respecto de** Alexis

Or even `acerca de`

> [acerca de](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0NqxnBE)
>
> 1. loc. prepos. Sobre aquello de que se trata, en orden a ello.

Translating as:

> Buenas tardes, soy María de *-business name-* y llamo/llamaba **acerca de** Alexis

Comment: how about "en cuanto a"?

Comment: @nylypej I don't think "en cuanto a" will work here. This prepositional phrase works when you change the topic. For example: *Quiero decirte esto a propósito de/con respecto a/acerca de Alexis* (you say what you have to say about Alexis, and then add:) *En cuanto a Alicia, su caso es diferente.*

Answer (score 2):

Among the other ansers' suggestions, I think "con relación a" is the most "accurate" of the translations.

However, I'd like to add that this structure is not very common when calling people. It's very interesting how each language has its own "telephone idioms".

So, my advise is not to try to find an exact equivalent. It is better to change the sentence in order to make it sound more natural. The expressions I'd use are

> (llamo) por

For example

> "Soy María, de *(business)*, llamo por Alexis.

But I think it's much better to use

> **Pregunto por**:
>
> Soy María, de *(business)*, pregunto por Alexis.

Nevertheless, I'd change the sentence even more. Just like the first part of the setnence: we don't say "Esta es María" for "This is María", we say "Soy María", or something similar, like "Me llamo María". Spanish is just different, so I'd suggest to use:

> ¿Hablo con Alexis?
>
> or
>
> ¿Podría hablar con Alexis?

Comment: Your last two suggestions suggest to me calling in order to talk to Alexis but the OP seems to want to talk to somebody about Alexis although it is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, now I see. I had understood it that way, but you're right. Then just "llamo **por** Alexis".